# Can I enter the United States on a Visa Waiver, go to Mexico and re-enter with an F1 visa?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, us-visa-waiver-program, f1-visas, transition-of-visa-status

I have seen this question being asked many many times but yet have not found a satisfying answer nor anyone with experience.

I have an F1 visa to study in the United States and I know I can only enter with that visa (status) maximum 30 days prior to the start date. However, I qualify for a Visa Waiver and would like to spend two months prior to my studies in the U.S. JUST traveling as a tourist. Can I leave to Mexico and re-enter on my F1 visa?

I know some people will say "you can only enter the U.S. on a Visa Waiver with a round-trip" but what if I BOOK a round trip and just don't take the trip back? I don't need to be lectured on the rules. I am simply asking if anyone has done it and what your experience with that was.

Comment: One option for those worried about the round-trip-ticket requirement is to fly to Canada or Mexico and enter by land.  The requirement does not apply to visitors entering by land.

Comment: You absolutely _don't_ need a round-trip ticket. You just need to show that you'll leave the US. They don't care if you're going back home or going to Timbuktu.

Answer (score 2):

Buy a fully-refundable return (or onward) ticket and cancel it after entering the US.

Having entered the US under the VWP, it is perfectly fine to exit to Mexico and re-enter in F1 status.

Your main concern will be convincing the officer on your first entry that you will be a genuine tourist for the two months preceding your studies (have documents proving your plans as clearly as possible).