# Visa Waiver Program-> Mexico -> F1 Visa

Tags: international-travel, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, f1-visas

I am a New Zealander wanting to clarify some travel plans for next month regarding my F1 visa to alleviate some anxiety!

Current itinerary is:

1. Fly NZ-US, enter on VWP ~60 days before class starts (with a return ticket) to visit friends/spend time with my partner.
2. Refund my return ticket once I've arrived.
3. Fly US-Mexico for a weekend ~25 days before class starts (such that I can re-enter on F1).
4. Fly Mexico-US, enter on F1 visa.

My main questions are:

- Will there be issues flying to/from Mexico? I see from many other posts
  that technically on the VWP you must not terminate your travel in Canada, Mexico or nearby Islands. **Is this relevant? as I will re-enter on a F1 visa, not via the VWP.**
- I know that travel to Canada/Mexico/nearby Islands count as part of the 90 day ESTA limit, so **will the days keep on accumulating once I re-enter on the F1 and eventually exceed 90? as I never technically left by this definition.**
- Will I be able to re-enter the US after only ~2days in Mexico?

Any advice would be much appreciated, thanks!

Similar to [this post here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/112540/can-i-enter-the-united-states-on-a-visa-waiver-go-to-mexico-and-re-enter-with-a?rq=1) from a few years back.

Comment: Your question sounds like a duplicate of the Q&A you linked as similar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I enter the United States on a Visa Waiver, go to Mexico and re-enter with an F1 visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/112540/can-i-enter-the-united-states-on-a-visa-waiver-go-to-mexico-and-re-enter-with-a)